# PAYPAL SDK PHP INTEGRATION V2 CHEKOUT. ERROR MISSING HEADER

Tags: php, paypal, sdk, headers, fixedheader

Buen día a todos,

Estoy haciendo una integración con PAYPAL V2, el flujo de trabajo ya me funciona todo. solo tengo un gran problema, cuando doy click al boton para que me redireccione a PAYPAl me rechaza y me muestra lo siguente, El flujo de trabajo esta bien, solo no logro que desde la pagina origen me abra la ventana de paypal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si abro la URL directamente con botón derecho en otra ventana, me direcciona sin problema y el flujo continua hasta terminar la compra, ya lo probé ONLINE y me arroja lo mismo.

Mi FRONT ES :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Ensures optimal rendering on mobile devices. -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> <!-- Optimal Internet Explorer compatibility -->
    <?php include ('layouts/utilities.php'); ?>
</head>

<body>
    <script
        src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AUvmZW-GI99S8UBfjXqA5BoZbvkuqVi3_T6NlJdPU9LMTCfAmsHexg1oXjHlKTs5fgMxr1iwLtjpGRfz">
    </script>

    <script>
    paypal.Buttons({
        createOrder: function() {
            return fetch('/mipagina/assets/paypal/CreateOrder.php', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    "intent": "CAPTURE",
                    "purchase_units": [{
                        "reference_id": "1",
                        "custom_id": "121",
                        "amount": {
                            "currency_code": "MXN",
                            "value": "100.00"
                        }
                    }]
                })

            }).then(function(res) {
                return res.json();
            }).then(function(data) {
                return data.id; // Use the key sent by your server's response, ex. 'id' or 'token'
            });
        },
        onApprove: function(data) {
            return fetch('/mipagina/assets/paypal/CreateOrder.php', {
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    orderID: data.orderID
                })
            }).then(function(res) {
                return res.json();
            }).then(function(details) {
                alert('Transaction funds captured from ' + details.payer_given_name);
            })
        }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    //This function displays Smart Payment Buttons on your web page.
    </script>
</body>
```

Mi SW donde inicia el flujo de Paypal (siguiendo la documentación de ellos)  es

```
introducir el código aquí
header("Origin: http://localhost:8888/miPagina/");
header('crossDomain: true');


require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
//1. Import the PayPal SDK client that was created in `Set up Server-Side SDK`.
include 'PayPalClient.php';
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersCreateRequest;

class CreateOrder
{

// 2. Set up your server to receive a call from the client
    /**
     *This is the sample function to create an order. It uses the
     *JSON body returned by buildRequestBody() to create an order.
     */

    public static function createOrders($debug = false)
    {

        $contentType = isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) ? trim($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) : '';

        if ($contentType === "application/json") {
            //Receive the RAW post data.
            $content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));

            $items = json_decode($content, true);

            //If json_decode failed, the JSON is invalid.
            if (!is_array($items)) {
                return "algo salio mal";
            } else if (!isset($items['purchase_units']) && !isset($items['intent'])) {
              return "algo salio mal";;
            }

        }
     
        $items = ($items['purchase_units']);

        $request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
        $clientStatus = new PayPalClient();

        $request->prefer('return=representation');
        $request->body = self::buildRequestBody($items);
        /*   echo json_encode($request);
        die(); */
        // 3. Call PayPal to set up a transaction
        $client = PayPalClient::client();

        try {
            // Call API with your client and get a response for your call
            $response = $client->execute($request);

            // If call returns body in response, you can get the deserialized version from the result attribute of the response
           // print_r($response);
           session_start();
           $_SESSION['paypal_order_id'] = strval($response->result->id);
            foreach ($response->result->links as $link) {
                if ($link->rel == "approve") {
                    header('Location:' . $link->href);
                }
            }
        } catch (HttpException $ex) {
            echo $ex->statusCode;
            print_r($ex->getMessage());
        }

        if ($debug) {
            print "Status Code: {$response->statusCode}\n";
            print "Status: {$response->result->status}\n";
            print "Order ID: {$response->result->id}\n";
            print "Intent: {$response->result->intent}\n";
            print "Links:\n";
            foreach ($response->result->links as $link) {
                print "\t{$link->rel}: {$link->href}\tCall Type: {$link->method}\n";
            }

            // To print the whole response body, uncomment the following line
            // echo json_encode($response->result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        }

        // 4. Return a successful response to the client.

        //return $response;
    }

    /**
     * Setting up the JSON request body for creating the order with minimum request body. The intent in the
     * request body should be "AUTHORIZE" for authorize intent flow.
     *
     */
    private static function buildRequestBody($items)
    {
        return array(
            'intent' => 'CAPTURE',
            'application_context' => array(
                'brand_name' => 'MI MARCA',
                'locale' => 'en-MX',
                'user_action' => 'PAY_NOW',
                'return_url' => 'http://localhost:8888/mipagina/assets/paypal/return.php',
                'cancel_url' => 'http://localhost:8888/mipagina/c.php',
            ),
            'purchase_units' => $items,
        );
    }
}

/**
 *This is the driver function that invokes the createOrder function to create
 *a sample order.
 */
if (!count(debug_backtrace())) {

    CreateOrder::createOrders(true);
}
```

Comment: Hola luis, al tener tu `header("Origin: http://localhost:8888/miPagina/");` el script cambia a `127.0.0.1`, por lo tanto paypal no puede procesar, ya lo haz intentado con un dominioo en linea?

Comment: Si tengo mi codigo en linea, ya quite el header Origin, y me arroja lo mismo, header missing